# Why Tab host not showing icon in android?

Tags: android, android-layout, tabs, android-tabhost, fragment-tab-host

Here is the code to setup the tabhost, however there are two problem

1. The text will go to next line if it is too long, can I reduce the
   size and force it to single line?
2. All icon do not show, even I am sure the image src is correct

   ```
   public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity {

       @Override
       protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
           super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
           setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

           FragmentTabHost tabHost = (FragmentTabHost)findViewById(android.R.id.tabhost);

           tabHost.setup(this, getSupportFragmentManager(), R.id.realtabcontent);
           tabHost.addTab(tabHost.newTabSpec("restaurant").setIndicator("Restaurant",getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.food)),PlaceList.class, null);
           tabHost.addTab(tabHost.newTabSpec("attraction").setIndicator("Attraction",getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.view)), PlaceList.class, null);
           tabHost.addTab(tabHost.newTabSpec("map").setIndicator("Map",getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.map)),Map.class,null);
           tabHost.addTab(tabHost.newTabSpec("planner").setIndicator("Planner",getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.plan)),Planner.class, null);
       }
    }
   ```

Comment: try to call `tabHost.setup()` without parameters.

Comment: Throw exception : Must call setup() that takes a Context and FragmentManager

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When calling `TabSpec.setIndicator`, the `Drawable` you pass in [will only be visible if the label is `null` or empty.](https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_base/blob/master/core/java/android/widget/TabHost.java#L641) As far as making sure the `TextView` is restricted to a single line goes, you could loop over `TabWidget.getTabCount`, then call `TabWidget.getChildTabViewAt` and `View.findViewById` to get the `TextView` used to set the title. After that just make a call to `TextView.setSingleLine`.

```
    final TabWidget tabWidget = tabHost.getTabWidget();
    for (int i = 0; i < tabWidget.getTabCount(); i++) {
        final View tab = tabWidget.getChildTabViewAt(i);
        final TextView title = (TextView) tab.findViewById(android.R.id.title);
        title.setSingleLine();
    }
```

Alternatively, you could inflate your own tab layout by creating a style for `Widget.TabWidget`.

```
<style name="Your.TabWidget" parent="@android:style/Widget.TabWidget">
    <item name="android:tabLayout">@layout/your_tab_layout</item>
</style>
```

In your parent theme create a new `item` for `android:tabWidgetStyle` to apply it.

Comment: Thanks. So the only way to keep the label and icon is to create custom tab layout?

Comment: You could call `TextView.setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds`.

Comment: `setIndicator` doc says _Specify a label and icon as the tab indicator_. This is really misleading.